# How to read files from Android external storage in MAUI application

Tags: c#, android, maui

How can I read/write all/specific files from an android external storage folder in a MAUI application. I know there are native ways to do that in Xamarin.Android but here I am looking for more modern abstract way to achieve it. Kindly help.

To be specific I am looking for some abstraction/API to list files on Android platform. something like below would be ideal or similar-

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(<FolderPath>)
```

Any pointer would really help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take .txt file as an example.

MainPage.xaml:

```
...
<VerticalStackLayout>
        <Button Text="File"
                Clicked="file_clicked"/>
        <Button Text="Read_file"
                Clicked="Read_file"/>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs, you can add this:

```
    
    //string targetFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "TextFile3.txt");

    // Write the file content to the app data directory
    private async void file_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
#if ANDROID
        //var docsDirectory = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments);
        //File.WriteAllText($"{docsDirectory.AbsoluteFile.Path}/atextfile.txt", "contents are here");
        var docsDirectory = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim);
        File.WriteAllText($"{docsDirectory.AbsoluteFile.Path}/atextfile.txt", "contents are here");
#endif


       //using FileStream outputStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(targetFile);
       //using StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream);
       //await streamWriter.WriteAsync("ssss");
    }

    //read file
    private async void Read_file(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
#if ANDROID
        var docsDirectory = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim);
        var a = File.OpenRead($"{docsDirectory.AbsoluteFile.Path}/atextfile.txt");
        using StreamReader reader_1 = new StreamReader(a);
        var doc = await reader_1.ReadToEndAsync();
        await DisplayAlert("content", doc, "OK");
#endif


       //using FileStream outputStream_2 = System.IO.File.OpenRead(targetFile);
       //using StreamReader reader_2 = new StreamReader(outputStream_2);
       //string content_2 = await reader_2.ReadToEndAsync();
       //content_2 = content_2.ToUpperInvariant();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I am looking for reading files from external storage folders like Download, DCIM etc. and not from AppData

Comment: @DivyaPrakashJha I edited the answer. Wish it can help you.

Comment: This is better. Thanks. In my MAUI app, where will I write this piece of code? in MainActivity.cs or MainApplication.cs (in Platforms/Android) or somewhere else in the solution.Note as mentioned in the question, My preference is to write platform agnostic code by avoiding Android native code, but if MAUI doesn't support that,then  I can write Android specific. Sorry please excuse my limited knowledge on MAUI/Android.

Comment: @DivyaPrakashJha They are two buttons Clicked event. You just need to write it in MainPage.xaml.cs. I updated the answer, hoping to make you better understand it.

Comment: It almost solves my problem except this code read/write file to DCIM folder under "application context" wherein I want from public/shared storage. Could you please provide alternative for that as well? Thanks in advance. To give you more info my app reads entire phone storage, processes file content and produce some data out of that. hence I need access to the files which are out of app context.

Comment: @DivyaPrakashJha You can try to use `System.Environment.GetLogicalDrives()` to get device file path. It seems impossible to read and write file from public/shared storage by your app. Because it involves privacy

Answer (score -1):

That is the way my android phone works. When you finally get the data to a external file you can read it to the laptop as an internal file. figure that one out. You read and write to an SDcard file.

I can not get that code to work on a samsung tablet. To read external files.

write and reading files by programming, i could only get it to work with the debugger (push and pull adb)external . i could not find any other method to program the file transfer from pc to android phone.

for now, i can only find the debugger method!!!

Comment: This is not an answer to the question being asked. This answer is about transferring files between pc and android. (And its not a useful answer even for that.) The question is about a Maui app accessing files in phone's external storage.